# Constructing elements of union

Tags: c++, constructor, unions, perfect-forwarding, move-constructor

The following class outputs when a constructor is called:

```
class A {
 public:

    A() {
        std::cout << "Default Constructor called at address:" << this << "!\n";
    }

    A(int val) : val_(val) {
        std::cout << "Secondary Constructor called at address:" << this << "\n";
    }

    A(A&& other) : val_(std::move(other.val_)) {
        std::cout << "Move constructor called from " << &other << " to " << this << "\n";
    }

    A& operator=(A&& other) {
        std::cout << "Move assignment called from " << &other << " to " << this << "\n";
        val_ = std::move(other.val_);
        return *this;
    }

 private:
    int val_;

};
```

This union allows me to skip the default constructor of `A`, which is desirable:

```
union MyUnion {
    MyUnion() {}
    A a;
};
```

My goal with `main` was to move-construct `a`. Instead it move-assigns the `a`.

```
int main(){

    MyUnion my_union[2];

    std::cout << "Entering for loop:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        my_union[i].a = std::move(A(i));
    }

    return 0;
    
}
```

An example output from the above main function is:

```
Entering for loop:
Secondary Constructor called at address:0x7ffcdd3553a8
Move assignment called from 0x7ffcdd3553a8 to 0x7ffcdd3553b0
Secondary Constructor called at address:0x7ffcdd3553a8
Move assignment called from 0x7ffcdd3553a8 to 0x7ffcdd3553b4
```

I wanted to move-construct, but I'm instead move-assigning. Move-assigning without move constructing is unsafe in general. The solution I came up with was to use `std::construct_at`. I also added a destructor. The full program with these modifications is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class A {
 public:

    A() {
        std::cout << "Default Constructor called at address:" << this << "!\n";
    }

    A(int val) : val_(val) {
        std::cout << "Secondary Constructor called at address:" << this << "\n";
    }

    A(A&& other) : val_(std::move(other.val_)) {
        std::cout << "Move constructor called from " << &other << " to " << this << "\n";
    }

    A& operator=(A&& other) {
        std::cout << "Move assignment called from " << &other << " to " << this << "\n";
        val_ = std::move(other.val_);
        return *this;
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Destructor called at " << this << "\n";
    }

 private:
    int val_;

};

union MyUnion {
    MyUnion() {
        std::cout << "MyUnion Constructor called!\n";
    }
    void ConstructAt(A&& other){
        std::construct_at(&a, std::forward<A>(other));
    }
    A a;
    ~MyUnion(){
        std::cout << "MyUnion Destructor called!\n";
        a.~A();
    }
};

int main(){

    MyUnion my_union[2];

    std::cout << "\nEntering for loop:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        my_union[i].ConstructAt(std::move(A(i)));
    }

    std::cout << "\nExiting for loop:\n";

    return 0;
    
}
```

This gives output:

```
MyUnion Constructor called!
MyUnion Constructor called!

Entering for loop:
Secondary Constructor called at address:0x7ffe38dd4838
Move constructor called from 0x7ffe38dd4838 to 0x7ffe38dd4840
Destructor called at 0x7ffe38dd4838
Secondary Constructor called at address:0x7ffe38dd4838
Move constructor called from 0x7ffe38dd4838 to 0x7ffe38dd4844
Destructor called at 0x7ffe38dd4838

Exiting for loop:
MyUnion Destructor called!
Destructor called at 0x7ffe38dd4844
MyUnion Destructor called!
Destructor called at 0x7ffe38dd4840
```

This appears to be what I want.

### Question

Was this the correct way to call the move constructor? Am I using `std::forward` correctly? Is this the correct way to handle the destructor of a union?

Comment: `std::move(A(i))` to a temporary is odd.

Comment: @273K I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean in ```MyUnion::ConstructAt```? If so, I struggle with forwarding and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You are sing `std::forward` incorrectly, `std::move` should be used.

Comment: The correct way is to use `std::variant` and spare yourself all these headaches, at an expense of a few bytes of RAM. RAM is cheap these days.

Comment: All usages of `std::move(A(i))` in the codes above are odd, because temporary is A&& w/o an explicit move.

Comment: @273K Oh, I see what you are saying. That just makes the ```std::move``` redundant, though, correct? I included ```std::move``` to make clear to stackoverflow users that I specifically want to call the move constructor. If I remove ```std::move```, that doesn't change the performance or correctness of the code. (I think)

Comment: @273K wait, are you saying ```std::construct_at(&a, std::forward<A>(other));``` should be ```std::construct_at(&a, std::move(other));```?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @273K I'm not following you. My first comment was about ```ConstructAt(std::move(A(i)));```. My second was about ```std::construct_at(&a, std::forward<A>(other));```. I don't know what "it" is.

Comment: @mbang: Is there some reason why you can't just use `optional<A>` for this, and just `emplace` when you want to construct one? It's C++17 (`construct_at` is C++20), so it's available to you. And it's way less code to deal with.

Comment: @NicolBolas performance reasons. I know exactly when in my code ```A a;``` will hold a valid value and when it won't. The code I'm writing is an alternative (more performant) implementation of some standard library functions. There's a small chance it may eventually be included with C++ compilers. I want to run up the score on performance.